# "I'll let you know once I have any" vs. "once I have some"

Tags: word-choice, american-english, modifiers, some-any

> I have no questions so far but I will let you know once I have any.

Is this grammatical, or should it be "... once I have some" instead?

Comment: 'Any' would cover the eventuality of only having one question.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* would be my normal choice there, because *once* can introduce a negative context. But *some* is also possible.

Comment: Very well said and in few words.

Comment: How does "once" introduce a negative context?

Comment: [Negative context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_polarity) is perhaps an unfortunate name for the phenomenon: the range of contexts that license _any_ and its derivatives might be better called "non-affirmative", since they include negative ("I haven't seen anyone"), interrogative ("Have you seen anyone?"),  conditional ("If you see anyone"). _Once_ in this sense is a little odd, because it does license _any_ where _when_ doesn't ("Once I have any" but "When I have some"). I think it is because _Once_ means something like _not until_, and so does contain a sort of negative.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely *any* in my view. Although the sentence is not strictly negative, as it does not preclude the possibility that there might be *some* questions, *at the moment there aren't any*. So to me it's implicitly negative, thus requiring *any*.

Notice that "once" in the sentence is a bit awkward, as it seems to imply a certainty that there *will* be questions. This might be your intention, but otherwise you might want to consider changing that:

> [...] I will let you know *if* I have any

Answer (score -1):

*Technically*, you would want to use "some" in this question as any is normally used with a negative and used to express a lack. E.g. "I don't have any plans for the weekend."

However, unless you are dealing with someone very pedantic, either is fine in your sentence. However, the words are not completely synonymous and there are situations were one is definitely correct and the other is not, as in my example sentence above.  You would definitely not want to say "I don't have some plans for the weekend."

https://magoosh.com/toefl/2014/any-vs-some/

Comment: No. "Once"can create a negative (non-affirmative) context. See my answer.

Comment: @ColinFine Does using "once" here seem off though?  I would almost certainly say "if" rather than "once" in this context.

Comment: seems perfectly normal to me. _if_ has a different meaning: it implies to me something like "I will go and check, and let you know if I have any". _Once_ implies "I expect to get some, and when I doI will let you know".